# How to nice/renice all the future processes of a user

Tags: linux, nice

One of my server's users needs to launch CPU and I/O intensive jobs that are also quickly done (usually less than 30 seconds). They can be started by a user’s cron, a user’s shell or even `Apache`, `PHP` or `MySQL` processes forked/launched from root’s processes (MySQL and Apache run as root then forked processes set themselves as the corresponding user).

Is there a way to nice an entire user and all its future processes owned by this user?

**EDIT**
Added more precision about the kind of processes targeted

Comment: "niceness" is inherited, so if you use "renice" (and in particular `renice -u username`) then everything that they do will run at the altered priority **until they log in again**. Do you want to handle future logins, and is the user wanting to help? If so their login file could just run another shell at a lower priority. If the user doesn't want to help then you probably want to start looking at cgroups.

Comment: What @icarus wrote + a question : Do you want the nice value of these processes to be increased or decreased (from default)

Comment: @icarus I probably had to mention that it also concerns `PHP` and `MySQL` processes spawned by `Apache`. Regarding the shell, users won’t even notice so it’s a good idea for when they’re using a shell, thanks

Comment: It is almost always a good idea to give as many details as possible, The question now might be one of Apache configuration. Is the user the sole user of the Apache instance? If so just renice that instance.

Comment: Didn’t think about it before you talk about inheritance. My bad. The user isn’t the only Apache user but is the only one to renice

Answer (score 1):

In Unix'es all the child processes inherit the niceness value of their parent, so you could simply renice the root process of the user, e.g. bash, and that'll solve this issue for you.

In the case when there is already a session active and you don't know which parent process to renice (or there are too many parent processes to renice manually), you could do that for all user processes:

```bash
sudo renice 20 --pid `ps -o pid --user USERNAME`
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726910/how-to-nice-renice-all-the-future-processes-of-a-user#comment1378308_726910

Comment: This answer applies to your situation as well. It's astonishing how little details you gave in your question and require people to follow on your comments. This is not how you ask questions on this website or in general. You can also edit a systemd init file to set the priority right on launch.

Comment: Sorry for redirecting you, I thought it would be better to redirect to a comment than to repeat myself, editing the post seems even better. Regarding your answer, you talk about inheritance while in case of Apache forks and PHP instances, new forks are new processes and wouldn’t inherit a user’s niceness, would it ?